# Обособленные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я обособила распространенное определение "важных для безопасности атомных станций"? 
Стандарт распространяется на детали и сборочные единицы из титановых сплавов, предназначенные для трубопроводов, эксплуатируемых в системах, важных для безопасности атомных станций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Распространенные определения, выраженные прилагательными с зависимыми словами, обособляются, если стоят после определяемого слова, поэтому Вы все сделали правильно

Comment: Да, я просто пыталась понять, не подходит ли этот случай под исключение. Но тут запятая, конечно, просто очевидна...

Answer (score 0):

Предложение стилистически небезупречно (три определительных оборота подряд), из-за чего и смысл понимается не сразу.

Предлагаемый вариант:Стандарт распространяется на детали и сборочные единицы из титановых сплавов, входящие в трубопроводы систем, важных для безопасности атомных станций.